# I cannot use JQuery hasClass function correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have two rows and I want to use jquery hasClass. if subjFull class has red class, it shows progressText. else if subjFull has green class, 
it shows progressTextNone. But this script doesn't work. How can I fix it?

```
 <tr class="cart-item-row">                         
   <div class="subjFull green"><a href="#">First</a></div>                                                            
   <div class="progressText">Minimum Price</div>
   <div class="progressTextNone">Max Price</div>                           
 </tr>
 <tr class="cart-item-row">                         
   <div class="subjFull red"><a href="#">Second</a></div>                                                            
   <div class="progressText">Minimum Price</div>
   <div class="progressTextNone">Max Price</div>                           
 </tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
if ($(".subjFull").hasClass("red")) {
   $(".progressText").show();
   $(".progressTextNone").hide();
 }

  else if ($(".subjFull").hasClass("green")) {
    $(".progressTextNone").show();
    $(".progressText").hide();
 }
<script>
```

Comment: Have you used the jQuery code inside `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: not a valid markup though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.each()` to iterate the `$(".subjFull")` then execute your code in the context of current element

Also you HTML is invalid. [`tr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) can only have `td`or `th` as its child

> Permitted content:    Zero or more `<td>` or `<th>` elements, or a mix of them

So wrap your div with the `td` like

```
<tr class="cart-item-row">
    <td>
          <div class="subjFull green"><a href="#">First</a>
          </div>
          <div class="progressText">Minimum Price</div>
          <div class="progressTextNone">Max Price</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".subjFull").each(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    var parent = _this.parent();

    if (_this.hasClass("red")) {
      parent.find(".progressText").show();
      parent.find(".progressTextNone").hide();
    }

    if (_this.hasClass("green")) {
      parent.find(".progressTextNone").show();
      parent.find(".progressText").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="cart-item-row">
    <td>
      <div class="subjFull green"><a href="#">First</a>
      </div>
      <div class="progressText">Minimum Price</div>
      <div class="progressTextNone">Max Price</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cart-item-row">
    <td>
      <div class="subjFull red"><a href="#">Second</a>
      </div>
      <div class="progressText">Minimum Price</div>
      <div class="progressTextNone">Max Price</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".subjFull").hasClass("red")) {
       $(".progressText").show();
       $(".progressTextNone").hide();
     }

      else if ($(".subjFull").hasClass("green")) {
        $(".progressTextNone").show();
        $(".progressText").hide();
     }
});
<script>
```